# Filtrar arbol de Select con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtro

Estoy iniciandome en JS y Jquery pero me tope con una idea que no la estoy resolviendo. Me gustaria una ayuda o una guia si no es molestia. Deseo hacer un Select en donde dependiendo del value me muestre una lista del id del un segundo select.

```
<select id="principal">
    <option value="1">Rock</option>
    <option value="1">Dance</option>
</select>

<select id="mostrar">
    <option value="RollingStone" id="1">Rolling Stones</option>
    <option value="Beatles" id="1">The Beatles</option>
    <option value="Tiesto" id="2">Tiesto</option>
</select>
```

Cualquier guia sera muy bien recibida. Saludos

Comment: Me gustaría poder ver tu avance de lo que llevas hasta ahorita, las preguntas deben de llevar un [mcve] y una explicación de cuál es el problema u error que genera.

Comment: Hola amigo, aquí hay una pregunta similar en ingles y tiene las soluciones. Espero que te ayude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351921/how-to-populate-a-cascading-dropdown-with-jquery

Comment: hola te dejo una explicacion mas menos de lo que quieres realizar http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Combo_que_depende_de_otro_Combo_con_Javascript_y_jQuery